# What is the ASP.NET Core way of setting TemplateInfo on a ViewDataDictionary

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In attempting to convert a project to Core I am running into an issue.

Pre-Core *System.Web.MVC.ViewDataDictionary* exposed a TemplateInfo property with both a getter and a setter property.  This allows us to set an HtmlFieldPrefix field that was the magic behind getting form fields in nested arrays to bind during a form POST.

We use it like this...

```
for (var c = 0; c < Model.Items.Count(); c++)
{
    for (var p = 0; p < Model.Items[c].ParticipantViewModels.Count; p += 1)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CheckoutPrices.cshtml", Model.Items[c].ParticipantViewModels[p],
            new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewData)
            {
                TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
                {
                    HtmlFieldPrefix = $"Items[{c}].ParticipantViewModels[{p}]"
                }
            })
    }
}
for (var c = 0; c < Model.UnscheduledItems.Count(); c++)
{
    for (var p = 0; p < Model.UnscheduledItems[c].ParticipantViewModels.Count; p += 1)
    {
        @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_CheckoutPrices.cshtml", Model.UnscheduledItems[c].ParticipantViewModels[p],
            new ViewDataDictionary(Html.ViewData)
            {
                TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
                {
                    HtmlFieldPrefix = $"UnscheduledItems[{c}].ParticipantViewModels[{p}]"
                }
            })
    }
}
```

The same partial view is used for 'Items' and 'UnscheduledItems' but the *HtmlFieldPrefix* value is what gives the partial view context. The partial view can then use regular HtmlHelpers to produce the html with the proper *name* attribute set.  In this example we use IdFor because this is a radio button but for other input types we use the helpers.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.SelectedPriceId, Model.Prices[p].Id, new { Id = Html.IdFor(m => Model.Prices[p]) })
```

Which produces HTML like this..

```
<input id="Items_0__ParticipantViewModels_0__Prices_0_" checked="checked" name="Items[0].ParticipantViewModels[0].SelectedPriceId" type="radio" value="VFdwSk5VMUVUVEZXU0VvMVpFYzBQUT09">
```

The problem that I am facing is that the TemplateInfo property on the .Net Core ViewDataDictionary does not expose a setter. Source: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ViewDataDictionary.cs

Looking for a clean solution to this problem and so far can't seem to find one.

Couple questions:

1. **How is one supposed to set TemplateInfo in .Net Core?**
2. **Is there a different way that we should be handling this?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please check BeginCollectionItem library for asp.net mvc, you can find a lot of articles on the web. there is a port for core as well https://github.com/saad749/BeginCollectionItemCore but i did not check it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found great solution: [MVC 6 VNext how to set HtmlFieldPrefix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39145109/mvc-6-vnext-how-to-set-htmlfieldprefix)

Solution recap:  Add an extension method like:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static Task<IHtmlContent> PartialAsync(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, string partialViewName, object model, string prefix)
    {
        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(htmlHelper.ViewData);
        var htmlPrefix = viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix;
        viewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix += !Equals(htmlPrefix, string.Empty) ? $".{prefix}" : prefix;
        return htmlHelper.PartialAsync(partialViewName, model, viewData);
    }
}
```

And consume it like:

```
@await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_CheckoutPricesV3.cshtml", Model.Items[c].ParticipantViewModels[p], $"Items[{c}].ParticipantViewModels[{p}]")
```

Comment: omg why is this not built in... I'd recommend it being in the root namespace.